# JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf (Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have an application that is currently in production now, and the app is connected to app center to check for crashes/errors. I'm having this certain error on the logs "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.MasterDetailPageRenderer'." but I do not know how it occurs, any help on how to replicate the scenario to produce the error or how to fix it?.

Comment: Same here : Xamarin Exception Stack:
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform+DefaultRenderer'.

Comment: your trying to acccess a disposed object. but I have no idea how to replicate it